# verificar usuário cadastrado PHP Mysqli

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, mysqli

Olá, não entendo quase nada de Php e mysqli. estou tentando implementar o sistema de usuários para o site, o registro já está funcionando porém consigo registrar com o mesmo email quantas vezes quiser.
Como eu verifico se já existe o email registrando no BD?

até agora só tenho isso, [Formulário "index.php"](http://houseofcoin.com/pt/) ;

config.php (faz a conexão com o banco de dados);

controleindex.php (enviando os valores pra tabela do BD)

```
﻿<?php
require_once("config.php");

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$sobre = $_POST['sobre'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];


$mysqli->query("Insert into usuarios (nome,sobre,email,senha) values ('".$nome."','".$sobre."','".$email."','".$senha."')")

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email'");
$row = $result->fetch_row();
if ($row[0] > 0) {
    $alerta =("E-mail (".$email.") já existente.");
} else {
    $mysqli->query("Insert into usuarios (nome,sobre,email,senha) values ('".$nome."','".$sobre."','".$email."','".$senha."')");
    $alerta =("Cadastro realizado com sucesso!!");
}

if ($alerta != ""){
echo ("<script language=\"javascript\" src=\"http://SeuDominio.com/fancybox/jquery-1.4.3.min.js\"></script>

<script language=\"javascript\" src=\"http://SeuDominio.com/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js\"></script>

<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"http://SeuDominio.com/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css\" 
media=\"screen\" />

<script type=\"text/javascript\">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $.fancybox(
        '".$alerta."',
        {
        'autoDimensions'    : false,
        'width'             : '300',
        'height'            : '50',
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none'
        }
        );
    });
</script>");
}
```

Comment: infelizmente, não deu certo... o código roda, mas não abre a fancybox e abaixo do "else" que cadastra tem um "}" a mais, é isso que eu estava querendo, mas Obrigado por tentar.

Comment: enviado, mas se quiser ver como ta o formulário com o código que você passou esse é o link http://houseofcoin.com/pt

Comment: Se for para mostrar uma mensagem assim, @ÉoRonaldoDll faz um ajax que o código fica mais bonito e legível.

Answer (score 7):

Basta verificar se já exite algum usuário com o e-mail passado

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuarios WHERE email = '{$email}'");
$row = $result->fetch_row();
if ($row[0] > 0) {
    echo "E-mail já cadastrado";
} else {
    $mysqli->query("Insert into usuarios (nome,sobre,email,senha) values ('".$nome."','".$sobre."','".$email."','".$senha."')");
}
```

Você deve prevenir injeção de SQL no seu código, do jeito que está escrito SQL pode ser facilmente injetado, [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php) tem uma explicação de como prevenir.

Comment: Nossa, muito obrigado!! só mais uma duvida, como eu posso colocar a mensagem como um alerta ou coisa do tipo? uso a $row pra fazer isso?

Comment: Aí depende do fluxo que você vai usar, você pode redirecionar o usuário para a mesma página do cadastro setando na sessão ou passando pela url uma valor para informar que o e-mail já foi cadastrado. Ex: `http://houseofcoin.com/pt/?msg=emailcadastro` aí você verifica se o ` $_GET['msg']` foi setado e mostrar a mensagem de acordo com esse valor. Ou ainda (uma solução não elegante), dar uma `alert` tipo assim: `"echo <script>alert('E-mail já cadastrado!')</script>"` e redirecionar para a página de cadastro.

Comment: @ÉoRonaldoDll só por curiosidade, reparei que aceitaste e desaceitaste esta resposta. Há alguma coisa que valia a pena corrigir/comentar ou que está em falta na resposta?

Comment: @Sergio estou apenas validando a resposta que mais se encaixa no problema, pra no futuro outros usuários possam se beneficiar com ela.

Comment: @ÉoRonaldoDll pois, a escolha é tua, sempre. Eu estava só curioso pois outros votaram nela e não tinhas deixado comentário para o autor perceber o que falhou ou o que pode estar em falta.

Comment: @Sergio realmente, foi um erro da minha parte...